# Draw big rectangle from selected tiles in grid

Tags: c++, grid

I have a 2d map grid system. When I hold the mouse down on a tile and move the mouse around to other tiles I want to draw the bigger rectangle that has the first tile as a one corner and the current tile as the other corner of the bigger drawn rectangle.

Currently I have the below but it's just a mess and growing. There must be an easier way to do this. Note the after I hold the mouse down over a tile I can move up/down/left/right to make the rectangle. My brain is fried and not able to break this down to be less code that I know it can be.

[image]

```
if (startBuyTile.col < mposTile.col)
                {
                    // use startBuyTile as top/left
                    // use current tile as bottom/right
                    int i = 0;

                    Vec2 spos = TileToWorldCoords(startBuyTile.row, startBuyTile.col);
                    spos.x = spos.x / 100;
                    spos.y = spos.y / 100;

                    if (startBuyTile.row < mposTile.row)
                    {
                        topLeft.x = spos.x - .64;
                        topLeft.y = 0;
                        topLeft.z = spos.y + .64;

                        bottomRight.x = pos.x + .64;
                        bottomRight.y = 0;
                        bottomRight.z = pos.y - .64;

                        topRight.x = spos.x + .64 + (1.28 * Math::Abs(colCount));
                        topRight.y = 0;
                        topRight.z = spos.y + .64;

                        bottomLeft.x = spos.x - .64;
                        bottomLeft.y = 0;
                        bottomLeft.z = pos.y - .64;
                    }
                    else if (startBuyTile.row > mposTile.row)
                    {
                        topLeft.x = pos.x - .64;
                        topLeft.y = 0;
                        topLeft.z = pos.y + .64;

                        topRight.x = spos.x + .64;
                        topRight.y = 0;
                        topRight.z = pos.y + .64;

                        bottomLeft.x = pos.x + .64;
                        bottomLeft.y = 0;
                        bottomLeft.z = spos.y - .64;

                        bottomRight.x = spos.x - .64;
                        bottomRight.y = 0;
                        bottomRight.z = spos.y - .64;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        topLeft.x = spos.x - .64;
                        topLeft.y = 0;
                        topLeft.z = spos.y + .64;

                        bottomRight.x = pos.x + .64;
                        bottomRight.y = 0;
                        bottomRight.z = pos.y - .64;

                        topRight.x = pos.x + .64;
                        topRight.y = 0;
                        topRight.z = pos.y + .64;

                        bottomLeft.x = spos.x - .64;
                        bottomLeft.y = 0;
                        bottomLeft.z = spos.y - .64;
                    }
                }
                else if (startBuyTile.col > mposTile.col)
                {
                    // use current tile as top/left
                    // use startBuyTile as bottom/right
                    int j = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    topLeft.x = pos.x - .64;
                    topLeft.y = 0;
                    topLeft.z = pos.y + .64;

                    topRight.x = pos.x + .64;
                    topRight.y = 0;
                    topRight.z = pos.y + .64;

                    bottomLeft.x = pos.x - .64;
                    bottomLeft.y = 0;
                    bottomLeft.z = pos.y - .64;

                    bottomRight.x = pos.x + .64;
                    bottomRight.y = 0;
                    bottomRight.z = pos.y - .64;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                topLeft.x = pos.x - .64;
                topLeft.y = 0; 
                topLeft.z = pos.y + .64;

                topRight.x = pos.x + .64; 
                topRight.y = 0; 
                topRight.z = pos.y + .64;

                bottomLeft.x = pos.x - .64; 
                bottomLeft.y = 0; 
                bottomLeft.z = pos.y - .64;

                bottomRight.x = pos.x + .64; 
                bottomRight.y = 0; 
                bottomRight.z = pos.y - .64;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Between the start tile and the tile I'm currently on I need to get the lowest row/col and highest row/col between them and that will give me my corners from which I can get my top left/right & bottom left/right points to make my rectangle.

I used min() and max() to get these corner tiles.